# keycloak Error! You need local access to create the initial admin user

Tags: keycloak

I am setting up Keycloack 18.0.0 behind AWS Application Load Balancer
Load Balancer listening on 443 (HTTPS) and forwarding requests to Port 8443, the default port of Keycloak.

1. Keycloak has been configured in production mode
2. I am using a self-signed certificate
3. Keycloak.conf image I have attached.
4. I also have added KEYCLOAK_ADMIN, and KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD in environment variables, please see attached screenshot of printenv command

With this I am able to access Keycloak home page but I am getting error
You need local access to create the initial admin user.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I also have added KEYCLOAK_ADMIN, and KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD

That's not correct. Keycloak must have those env variables configured, when it is starting, not your user.